# Display an option to upload image before click on Product images

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, product-images, product-view

We are Providing an option for customer to upload product image from frontend.

once we visit [product page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , we need to click on small image present below Product base image.

[image]

Than we need to click on Product image.

[image]

than only it will display an option to **upload an image** below Product Name.

[image]

Instead of this what we need is by default it should display an option to upload an image if value of **Input Type** under **"custom options"** is **Custom Product Preview**

[image]

```
initPreview: function()
    {
        var scale = this.option.calcScale(),
            elementId = this.config.previewContainer,
            container = $(elementId),
            c      = this.config,
            area   = c.area,
            thumb  = c.productImage.thumb;
        this.previewScale = scale;

        var areaParams = {
            width : Math.round(area.sizeX   * scale),
            height: Math.round(area.sizeY   * scale),
            left  : Math.round(area.offsetX * scale),
            top   : Math.round(area.offsetY * scale)
        };

        var html =
                '<div class="aitraph aitraph-bot"></div>' +
                '<img class="aitcg_preview_bg" src="' + thumb.fullUrl + '" />'+
                '<div class="aitraph aitraph-top"></div>' +
                '<div class="aitcg-overlay" style="width:'+ thumb.sizeX +'px;height:'+thumb.sizeY+'px;"></div>';
        container.update(html);

        this._showPreviewBlock( container );

        container.observe('click', this.onPreviewClick.bind(this));

        var title         = c.editorEnabled ? c.text.thumbTooltipEdit : c.text.thumbTooltipPreview,
            viewIconClass = c.editorEnabled ? '' : 'view-icon';
        container.select('.aitcg-overlay')[0]
            .observe('mouseover', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().update(title).show()})
            .observe('mouseout', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().hide()})
            .addClassName(viewIconClass);


        var styleParams = Aitcg.addPxToValue(areaParams);
        $$('#' + elementId + ' .aitraph').each( function(element) {
            element.setStyle(styleParams);
        });

        Aitoc_Common_Events.dispatch('aitcg_option_preview_create_after_' + this.id, {element: container});

        this.preview = new Aitcg_Editor(this.option);
        this.preview.init(container, Aitcg_Editor.MODE_PREVIEW, true, this.previewScale);
        this.preview.load( $('options_' + this.id).getValue() );

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery( "#aitcg_image_container1" ).trigger( "click" );` made the trick.....

```
 initPreview: function()
        {
            var scale = this.option.calcScale(),
                elementId = this.config.previewContainer,
                container = $(elementId),
                c      = this.config,
                area   = c.area,
                thumb  = c.productImage.thumb;
            this.previewScale = scale;

            var areaParams = {
                width : Math.round(area.sizeX   * scale),
                height: Math.round(area.sizeY   * scale),
                left  : Math.round(area.offsetX * scale),
                top   : Math.round(area.offsetY * scale)
            };

            var html =
                    '<div class="aitraph aitraph-bot"></div>' +
                    '<img class="aitcg_preview_bg" src="' + thumb.fullUrl + '" />'+
                    '<div class="aitraph aitraph-top"></div>' +
                    '<div class="aitcg-overlay" style="width:'+ thumb.sizeX +'px;height:'+thumb.sizeY+'px;"></div>';
            container.update(html);

            this._showPreviewBlock( container );

            container.observe('click', this.onPreviewClick.bind(this));

            var title         = c.editorEnabled ? c.text.thumbTooltipEdit : c.text.thumbTooltipPreview,
                viewIconClass = c.editorEnabled ? '' : 'view-icon';
            container.select('.aitcg-overlay')[0]
                .observe('mouseover', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().update(title).show()})
                .observe('mouseout', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().hide()})
                .addClassName(viewIconClass);


            var styleParams = Aitcg.addPxToValue(areaParams);
            $$('#' + elementId + ' .aitraph').each( function(element) {
                element.setStyle(styleParams);
            });

            Aitoc_Common_Events.dispatch('aitcg_option_preview_create_after_' + this.id, {element: container});

            this.preview = new Aitcg_Editor(this.option);
            this.preview.init(container, Aitcg_Editor.MODE_PREVIEW, true, this.previewScale);
            this.preview.load( $('options_' + this.id).getValue() );
            // jQuery( "#aitcg_image_container1" ).trigger( "click" );
        },
```